# Apache unresponsive when using NFS on Windows with Vagrant

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, nfs

I'm using Laravel Homestead (Vagrant) to set up my development environment. Everything works fine, until I try setting up NFS on my Windows following https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#configuring-shared-folders

As soon as I set up NFS, the `vagrant up` process goes fine, but trying to access the project website makes it unresponsive, i.e. no reply from the server. Opening `vagrant ssh`, only the place where the shared folder is present is unresponsive (bash gets unresponsive), otherwise other parts of the shell keep working.

More than a day of debugging later I find that simple files are actually working fine. So if `index.php` contains `phpinfo();`, that loads fine. I then copied the Laravel public folder, all good with an error that `vendor` is missing. Added the `vendor` folder, still good, says Kernal missing. And finally when I add the `app\Http\Kernal.php` file, again it gets unresponsive.

*Edit: Adding the following `mount_options` finally gets it working, but instead of being a lot faster, it is actually taking double the time it takes without NFS. My aim here is to improve the app loading speed, which everyone says gets a lot lot faster with NFS.*

`mount_options: ['vers=3', 'tcp', 'actimeo=1', 'nolock']`

*Edit 2: After a lot more debugging I noticed `realpath()` in PHP was coming out empty, after which I realized I'm unable to change file permissions of the shared folder! So the index.php has 644 permissions, and I'm totally unable to change those permissions or owner:group. I tried changing mount_options dmode and fmode, they don't have any effect*

*Future update: I eventually moved to Docker and later Laravel Sail and its magically fast*

Comment: You'll have to install the vagrant winnfsd plugin for the performance boost you're looking for https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd

Comment: @PtrTon Already did that

Comment: I don't know much about laravel and am not familiar with nfs on windows, but I guess you are serving your site as a service. Are you sure that the user running this service can access your shared folder ?

Comment: @Tuckbros Yup, like I mentioned the entire site works just fine without NFS, and now even with NFS with the additional `mount_options`

Comment: In the background a process called something along the lines of winnsfd.exe is run when you `vagrant up` with the plugin active. Please check if that process is not blocked by a firewall and antivirus software. Additionally you might need to change some network sharing settings from public to private or vice versa.

Comment: @PtrTon yeah its running. I just noticed Vagrant-Winnfsd was last updated 3 years ago.

Comment: @PtrTon, I made another Edit to the question, seems like I'm unable to change file permissions when `ssh`ing for the shared files

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the max `rsize` and `wsize` for `tcp` in your mount options, you would also probably want to set asynchronous mode and force nfs to use `fs-cache`.

e.g.

```
mount_options: ['async','fsc','nolock','vers=3','tcp','rsize=65536','wsize=65536','noatime','actimeo=1']
```

You could also try the mount over udp to see if that resolves the issue, I would also try simplifying the mount options at this point to see if it is something there causing the issue you are having.

```
mount_options: ['vers=3','udp','rsize=8192','wsize=8192']
```

Comment: This gives the same result as what I mentioned in "Edit", the speed is about 3-4x slower than without NFS

Comment: The edited options once again cause it to get stuck forever. Please do see my Edit2. That brought some progress after I set group and user to www-data but still wasn't able to set fmode and dmode successfully, they just won't change. After changing user and group, the "unresponsive" problem resolves without touching other `mount_options`